# Run Commands From Frontend Client in a Kubernetes Pod Using Python Kubernetes Client

Tags: python, linux, docker, kubernetes, terminal

I am trying to build a Linux Playground using Django, Django Channels, Docker, and Kubernetes. Technically, how this would work is a user will head to the terminal route where a terminal-like interface will be displayed and they will be able to run Linux commands and interact with it just like they are interacting with an actual Linux Terminal.

The workflow will be as follows:

1. User will head to the /terminal route and enter a command
2. The command will be passed to the backend via WebSocket
3. The backend will execute the command in a different Kubernetes pod created specifically for the user.

Here is what I have on the backend:

```
class TerminalConsumer(WebsocketConsumer):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        config.load_incluster_config()  # Load the in-cluster configuration
        configuration.assert_hostname = False
        self.core_api = client.CoreV1Api()  # Create a CoreV1Api instance

    def connect(self):
        print("CONNECTING")
        self.accept()

    def disconnect(self, close_code):
        pass

    def receive(self, text_data):
        text_data_json = json.loads(text_data)
        command = text_data_json['message']

        try:
            output = self.execute_command_in_pod(command)
            logging.info(f"SENDING: \n{output}")
            self.send(text_data=json.dumps({'message': output}))
        except Exception as e:
            self.send(text_data=json.dumps({'message': str(e)}))

    def execute_command_in_pod(self, command):
        pod_name = 'linux-playground'  # The name of the Pod running the Linux Playground
        namespace = 'default'  # The namespace in which the Pod is running
        container_name = 'linux-playground'  # The name of the container inside the Pod

        command_list = ['/bin/bash', '-c', command]

        # Execute the command inside the Pod and stream the output
        resp = stream.stream(
            self.core_api.connect_get_namespaced_pod_exec,
            name=pod_name,
            namespace=namespace,
            container=container_name,
            command=command_list,
            stderr=True,
            stdin=False,
            stdout=True,
            tty=False,
            _preload_content=False,
        )

        output_str = ""
        while resp.is_open():
            resp.update(timeout=60)
            if resp.peek_stdout():
                stdout_data = resp.read_stdout()
                logging.info(f"STDOUT: \n{stdout_data}")
                output_str += stdout_data
            if resp.peek_stderr():
                stderr_data = resp.read_stderr()
                logging.info(stderr_data)
                output_str += stderr_data

        if resp.returncode != 0:
            raise Exception("Script failed")

        # Close the stream
        resp.close()

        return output_str
```

This works as expected; I can run the command in the pod specified and get back the output, but the problem is I lose the state when I run the second command. For example, if I `cd` into some directory, the second command will not run in the directory I checked into.

What could be a potential solution for production-grade applications?

Answer (score 0):

Enabling sticky sessions for your kubernetes cluster will solve this issue. The issue you are facing now is caused because when you have entered your first command it is going for one pod/shell and then the connection is getting terminated now the new command will be taken as a new session and will be executed in a separate pod/shell.

In general all these types of lab environments will have a session timer, so based on your resource availability and scalability you can fix the session timing and this session needs to be a sticky session.

[**Istio**](https://istio.io/latest/) helps you to configure sticky sessions for kubernetes clusters. The rough Idea is from your backend the request will be going to Istio which will keep the connection alive till the session duration gets complete.

> The following example sets up sticky sessions for the ratings service
> hashing-based load balancer for the same ratings service using the
> User cookie as the hash key.

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: DestinationRule
metadata:
  name: bookinfo-ratings
spec:
  host: ratings.prod.svc.cluster.local
  trafficPolicy:
    loadBalancer:
      consistentHash:
        httpCookie:
          name: user
          ttl: 0s
```

**Note:** This example is taken from the [**Istio official documentation**](https://istio.io/latest/docs/reference/config/networking/destination-rule/#:%7E:text=The%20following%20example%20sets%20up%20sticky%20sessions%20for%20the%20ratings%20service%20hashing%2Dbased%20load%20balancer%20for%20the%20same%20ratings%20service%20using%20the%20the%20User%20cookie%20as%20the%20hash%20key.).

Comment: Nope. For experimentation's sake, I just have one pod and I am running all my commands there. The issue is each command is running in a new shell

Comment: @Harith even if that's the case this sticky sessions configuration will help you in solving the issue

Comment: @Harith is your issue resolved revert back if you are still facing any issues so that we can assist you..